# jQuery alternatives for multiplayer games?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

First off, I am not asking for any code or anything like that.

all I need is some advise.

I'm creating a roulette game and everything in my roulette game is based on jQuery.

however, as we all know, jQuery is client side so I was thinking about using AJAX to send some details back to server and from the server to the users browser so I can make this roulette game work in "multiplayer" fashion... But the issue is that I don't think its possible to send the roulette's wheel animation to the server and back to users browser so I am a bit confused about this!

In my research I came across some information (old ones) about using node.js and jquery together! I don't know if this is possible or how easy it would be to use my jquery code in node.js as I have never used node.js before..

so the question that i have is:

- based on the information i provided above and my requirements, what are my options?
- can I use AJAX to achieve what i am trying to do and if so, a bit
  information would be great.
- if AJAX is out of question, is it possible to use my jquery code in
  node.js to achieve what I am trying to do?

ANY ADVISE WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

P.S. I don't want to use HTML5 as 1st I don't know much about HTML5 and also, some devices, browsers do not support it.

Thanks

Comment: "But the issue is that I don't think its possible to send the roulette's wheel animation to the server and back to users browser so I am a bit confused about this!" - you would not send the animation from server to the browser and vice versa but the data about the roulette wheel for example - which then influences the animation client-side.

Comment: @northkildonan, this is a bit confusing! how is it possible to send the animation data (specifically a wheel spinning animation data) to the server!

Comment: i don't know how your animation exactly works - but in the simplest case you would just send the current rotation angle of the wheel. but in case of roulette this wouldn't make much sense i guess - because it's all just about the number the ball gets in. so it would maybe make more sense if you have a `start spinning`, some `loopable spinning` and some `result` animation. so the server then would tell the client to play the start-animation, which turns into the loopable spinning.. and then the server tells the clients to play the result animation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use websockets to ensure real time communication. One of the best alternatives for implementing that could be using a server under node.js. Have a look to this video from Code School node.js tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtDK4jf4RS0 where is ilustrated how to implement a real time chat. Your problem is based on the same.

Comment: Your problem is based on the same. No, not really.. unless I'm missing something... I have created many AJAX/PHP chat applications and it was easy because there is no Animation involved in CHAT application but in this case, I am dealing with roulette wheel animation!

Comment: Animation is solely a client-side problem. You will never communicate details concerning animation with the server, you will just ask the server "What number was chosen?" and adjust the animation in the client based on the information you get.

Comment: @hon2a, I understand that... but what I need to know is that How I can display the same animation that user 1 sees for user 2 and user 3 and user 4 etc etc who are on the same roulette page!

Comment: A suppose the wheel is animated executing some client side function with some parameters, isn't it? So via websockets send the same order to execute the same in the other game players, so the result would be the same.

Comment: the game (the code) is solely written in jQuery which is a client side! is it possible to use jquery with websockets?

Answer (score 1):

There are three parts to a multiplayer game displayed in a browser:

1. client-side display,
2. server-side data management,
3. client-server communication.

If you're already set on your display technology (jQuery), then you're probably going to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for client-server communication. However, technologies used for server-side data management are completely up to you and they don't necessarily have any connection to the technologies used for display and communication (meaning the traditional communication initiated by client).

Basically, use any kind of server technology stack you like. `Node.js` might do just fine but there are many other viable alternatives. They just need to support communication with the client.

---

So, to be absolutely clear, your question doesn't really make sense. You might use `jQuery` in the client and `Node.js` on the server, but they will never really "work together". They will manage completely separate parts of your application and connect through protocols not specific to either of them.

As for the animation, the animation itself is solely a client-side problem. If you want to "synchronize the animation" across multiple clients, you can let the clients communicate with the server, but they only ever need to send/receive plain data. Then you adjust the client-side animation based on the received data.

As another poster points out, websockets are a better fit for this than regular client-initiated HTTP requests. Not because of "the animation", but because you want all the clients to receive the information about the start of betting at the same time.

Comment: what part of my question doesn't make sense?! you've already answered some of my question so how doesn't it make sense?

Comment: I was referring to your other comment _"Can I use jQuery with Node.js?"_

Comment: well, yes, That is the main question! so jQuery does the "client side" stuff and AJAX or node.js does the server side and the communicate with jQuery!!!! see, thats why I stated that I'm quite confused! :)

Comment: I should've explained it a bit better maybe.. the main issue that I have is this: what I need to know is that How I can display the same animation that user 1 sees for user 2 and user 3 and user 4 etc etc who are on the same roulette page!

Comment: `jQuery` is really just a JavaScript library. It doesn't communicate with anything, it just provides you with the `$.ajax()` shortcut for letting the _browser_ communicate with the _server_. The server doesn't need to know anything about what's used for communication on the client-side, it just responds to HTTP requests.

Comment: I think you  gave me an idea! here is what i have in mind at this stage! 1st- I will let the users to enter a roulette game, 2nd- they will press/click on a button to spin the roulette wheel, 3rd- this button will update the MYSQL database (i will create a colum in the database and call it spin with value 0), and the users button submit will change the value of this 1. 4th- the PHP/AJAX will go through database every X seconds and if the value changes to 1 then it will execute the jQuery for wheel animation in that page for all the users who are viewing the roulette table!

Comment: does that make sense or I'm just barking mad?

Comment: Basically. But you might want to notify clients of "wheel spin start" at the same time (using websockets or [long polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)) and then notify them at the same time about "end of betting" (and the number that the wheel "stopped at").

Comment: I'm keep getting thrown with this websocket and how I can use it!

Answer (score 1):

I am also developing a MMO game using javascript only. Firstly, there are two different types of javascript here. Usual client side javascript (the one you already know) and the server side javascript (i.e. Node.js).

You will need to develop both client and server before connecting them with jQuery's Ajax. So you need to study Node.js before designing overall architecture of your game.

I read many Node.js tutorials and watched many youtube tutorial videos but I was still confused, before I really sat down and read a good textbook that explained from basics, one like below. Try to get hold of it from your local library.

**Express web application development learn how to develop web applications with the Express framework from scratch** by Hage Yaapa

Express is the popular framework that runs on Node.js now. So it's worth getting familiar with Express Framework. Once you understand how express app works (not so difficult), you will see how you can frame your game structure like I did :)

In order for many clients to share same animation, there must a server that synchronizes the game state. Ajax can only link between server-client communication in my understanding. There is no mechanism that connects between clients. The clients ask server what number was the result of roulette roll and show the corresponding animations.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can use NodeJS and jQuery together.

NodeJS is *server-side*, meaning that you set up a server (a lot of people use the `Express` module, which is easy to use), which serves content to clients asking for it. Your server-side code can be in any language supporting sockets, not just NodeJS. But NodeJS is easy to use if you know JS already.

jQuery is *client-side*, meaning that it's executed by the user's browser, and may or may not have a server-side component (if it doesn't need it), *or* it might have one where it sends requests to the server-side code. When it requests a page from the server, it can be static content (like when you request `index.html`) or dynamic via an AJAX request. Client-side browser code must be HTML/CSS/JS (you can't make Firefox or Chrome interpret `C`, for example).